# Having an issue scraping data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract the *"**Salary"*** information from this [link](https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/Atse8Mz9mIOW-Python-Developer-EBE-Giza-Egypt?o=1&l=sp&t=sj&a=python%7Csearch-v3%7Chpb)
I'm using BeautifulSoup library, but the elements I'm selecting doesn't extract anything!.

[image: The image shows what element I'm selecting]

***Can you please checkout my code, and tell me what I'm doing wrong? or there is other libraries i should use ?***

```
#Importing the libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

#Loading the page + saving the content + parsing
result = requests.get("https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/Atse8Mz9mIOW-Python-Developer-EBE-Giza-Egypt?o=1&l=sp&t=sj&a=python|search-v3|hpb")
src = result.content
soup = bs(src,'html.parser')

#selecting the element and saving ir
salary = soup.find("section", {"class":"css-3kx5e2"}).find_all("span", class_ = "css-4xky9y")

#printing the elements as it is just for testing
print(salary)
```

Comment: All of the items in the Job Details section are added dynamically by JS. That's why you're not extracting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do "view source" and look for `Wuzzuf.initialStoreState`. The data is there as a json.
All you need to do is get the src (use requests), find the line and read the data as dict.